# Is there any reasons to use HTML5 for SEO at the moment?

Tags: html, seo, web-crawler

Or just `crawlers` ignore HTML5 new-tags (like `<article>`, `<section>`, `<video>`, `<nav>`, and so on...) indexing the pages?

For example, speaking about google-crawler, I found only old articles like [this](http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/023106.html) (2 years ago).

Maybe the rules have been changed?!?

Comment: Explain to me why people vote to close this question; really, I don't find it so stupid :O

Comment: The question is not stupid. It is off-topic here. It belongs to webmaster.stackexchange.com

Comment: Because there is no definite answer to SEO. Does Google publish their indexing algorithm? Do any of their competitors? No. So SEO is mostly a guessing game, and the rules change all the time. Just make the best content available in the best format you can, then the search engines will find you. That's what *they* are trying to optimize for.

Comment: "Just make the best content available in the best format you can" yeah, but should be google that must says to me "which are the right" rules :)

Comment: Then use HTML 5! The new semantic markup will make it easier for anybody to work with the content, including yourself. That's a better format. Google will find it, sooner or later. Even if they don't care about the added semantics of HTML 5 today (and I bet you they do already), they will tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I don't think much have changed since that article was written. If you're just thinking about using HTML5 for SEO, then don't. However, if you want to use HTML5 for other reasons, then go ahead. A lot of HTML5 features are still not supported by all browsers so watch out for that if you care about cross-browser support when you build websites.
Personally, I'm using the HTML5 doctype when coding, but I still don't use any of the new HTML5 elements. I do use some CSS3, but I make sure everything's OK in all major browsers before proceeding.

Again, HTML5 won't give you any advantage in search engine listings as far as I know, but as long as you keep your markup semantic, your content fresh and about topic you'll climb the listings.